# Random HTML page script working on edge and not on chrome

Tags: javascript

I have a script that randomly calls an HTML page inline with some JS. 
It's working fine on Edge, but not on chrome.  How do I get it to work on Chrome?

Tried to change the head, but I can't figure out what's wrong.

```js
function loadExternalHTMLPage() {
  var xmlhttp;
  var pagesToDisplay = ['1.html', '2.html'];
  
  if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
    xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  } else {
    xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
  
  xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
      document.getElementById("contentArea").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
    }
  }
  
  var randomnumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * pagesToDisplay.length);
  xmlhttp.open("GET", pagesToDisplay[randomnumber], true);
  xmlhttp.send();
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>Random principle</title>
</head>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="javascript.js"></script>

<body onload="loadExternalHTMLPage()">
  <div id="contentArea">
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Do you get an error in chrome? (check with F12 in the console tab.)

Comment: Hi Roland, 

Yes I do, but I don't know what to do about it.

javascript.js:16 Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'file:///C:/Users/eboucher/Desktop/Random-ecommerce/1.html' from origin 'null' has been blocked by CORS policy: Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https.

Comment: you need to host your application, to make ajax request.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use some server to host the files when you are using XMLHttpRequest to load the file. In case you are using the VS code as code editor, you can install the Live server extension and open the file using the Live server.

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ritwickdey.LiveServer